# MWeb failed publishing to Evernote with "Error Domain=com.evernote.sdk Code=11"

Tags: editor, markdown, evernote

I use [MWeb](https://www.mweb.im/) to write markdown documents. Recently I met a problem when I publish markdown document to Evernote, this is the error code:

`Error Domain=com.evernote.sdk Code=11 
"Content of submitted note was malformed" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Content of submitted note was malformed, parameter=Element type "row" must be declared.}`

[mweb-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdDEy.png)

Comment: See how to turn this into inline code, and ask a more specific question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root cause:

I used "Raw" in the doc, I think word "Raw" maybe a keyword in Evernote API. So if I add "Raw" in the doc, a raw definition must be declared.

## My solution

surrounding the word "Raw" with ``. For example:

change "Java API, users need to use Dataset to represent a DataFrame." to "Java API, users need to use `Dataset` to represent a DataFrame."